# Problemas con ciertos caracteres en los script

Tags: r, script, utf-8

¡Hola!

Escribo los script de RStudio en castellano, por lo que empleo tildes, la letra ñ, . . .
Estos caracteres pueden suponer un problema a la hora de leer documentos ya que pueden ser modificados por `?`. Pensaba que guardando el documento en formato UTF-8 este problema estaba solucionado, pero a veces, abro un fichero que llevo tiempo sin utilizar y se me desconfigura todo apareciendo la interrogación en lugar del símbolo correspondiente.

¿Alguna idea de cómo poder solucionar este problema?

Comment: En el menú archivo está la opción "reopen with encoding" (generalmente 5to elemeneto) que permite seleccionar la codificación de caracteres si el documento no lo incluye. Prueba con ISO8859, WINDOWS1252, UTF-8, etc.

Comment: ¡Gracias @RicVillalba! No he logrado solucionarlo del todo, pero desconocía esa funcionalidad y algunas palabras sí que me las escribe bien tras modificar el formato de apertura.